# Is it possible to host a blog externally and have it appear under a /blog/ sub directory

Tags: linux, windows, php, wordpress

A client has a website built in .NET on a Windows server and their provider will not install PHP and MySQL on it.

Is there a way to externally host a Wordpress blog and have it appear in a sub directory on the Windows server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the blog on a subdomain, as stated in your question, you could achieve this via DNS configuration: Just let the subdomain `blog.domain.com` point to the server with the wordpress blog.

If you want it on a subdirectory, as stated in your subject, you could achieve this by setting up a reverse proxy directive for this in your webserver config. On apache, you can use `mod_proxy` for this:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html